# Angular 5 sidenav

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use a bootstrap side navbar.

```
<nav id="sidebar"   [(class.slide-in)]="slideIn"  >
     <div class="sidebar-header">
         <img alt="Home" height="65" src="/assets/images/angular-logo.png" title="Home" width="150" class="ng-star-inserted">
     </div>

     <ul class="list-unstyled components">
         <p>Content</p>
         <li id="sidebar-list" style="border:2px;">  
             <a [routerLink]="['/HistoryOfAngular']">History of Angular</a>
         </li>
         <li id="sidebar-list">
             <a href="#">Hello World</a>
         </li>
         <li id="sidebar-list">
             <a href="#">Data Binding</a>
         </li>


     </ul>-->
</nav>

<!-- Page Content Holder -->
<div id="content">

     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
               <button (click)="toggleSidebar()"   style="margin:0px;border-radius: 0px;     height: 50px;" type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
                    <span>MENU</span>

               </button>
           </div>
       </nav>
```

I am toggling the side nav with some js code in  tag but the script tag doesnt run in angular 5. How could I toggle it. I thought have some code in my .ts file like

```
   toggleSidebar():void{
     }
```

Im not sure of what to put in it to toggle it. The code to toggle in the script tag is

```
   <script >
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
                 $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');

                   console.log("HII");
             });
         });
         console.log("HII");
  </script>
```

Comment: What Bootstrap library are you using, and which version? You have some obvious errors but to be able to help you out you need to provide us with some more information.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: This is what I'm using

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <b>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    Title
                </a>
            </b>
            <button type         ="button" 
                    class        ="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
                    data-toggle  ="collapse" 
                    data-target  ="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
                    aria-expanded="false">

                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="route1">Route1</a></li>
                <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="route2">Route2</a></li>
                <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="route3">Route3</a></li>       
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is from https://bootswatch.com/darkly/